# App rejected: Your app crashed on the iPad running iOS 10.3.3 connected to an IPv6 network

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ipv6

My app just got rejected by apple due to IPv6 I think:

Here is the message:

> Your app crashed on the iPad running iOS 10.3.3 connected to an IPv6
>   network when we:
>
> 1. Launched the app
> 2. Tapped on “How to use app” button (Produces Crash)
>
> We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

I know there is plenty of question like mine, I've looked a bit and found that I could test the IPv6 thing using the `sharing` propriety of the mac following [this tutorial](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-test-your-app-for-ipv6-compatibility/).

The thing is that once setup I don't know what to do to test it. 
Plus the function I use to send request was found here on SO, so I'm a bit surprised it's not IPv6 compatible:

```
func request(urlAdress: String){
    let url = URL(string: urlAdress)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in

        guard let datas = data, error == nil else { return }

        let responseStrin = NSString(data: datas, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print(responseStrin)
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

I'd like to be sure that it' because of IPv6, and not about something else (I've corrected the problem with the page after the button "How to use app").

Is the `request` function compatible with the IPv6 protocol?

Comment: Does it crash in your test under IPv6 network?

Comment: All of the Foundation networking types are IPv6 compatible without you having to worry about it. My guess is that you should be testing to see if your server is IPv6 compatible

Comment: @Shebuka the thing is that I don't know how to test the IPv6, I'm pretty new to swift and Apple environment.

Comment: It may be nothing to do with ipv6, Apple are just telling you about the environment where they performed the test. You need to symbolicate the crash log and determine where the crash occurred and what the exception message is.

Comment: Apple uses the "ipv6" rejection reason for any problem in an app. What matters here is not "ipv6" compatibility, it's **"Your app crashed"**. So identify and fix the crash issue, then re-submit to Apple.

Comment: @Cœur That's a bit what I had in mind in fact, but as I've never tested with IPv6 just wanna make sure. Logs they send is not very useful as it don't say where they were...

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, what I think too in fact... Thanks.

Comment: I also had the similar issue and my app got rejected because they were not able to log in. The issue was my backend server and the domain was not compatible with ipv6 networks. If the issue is related to ipv6, you don't need to make any changes in the front end of the application. You need to make changes in back end so that the domain supports ipv6 network

Comment: Check whether the URLs which you are hitting are loading in a web browser in an ipv6 network.

Comment: If you follow the instructions in your link and connect to the `NAT64` network with your iOS device, you'll be using IPv6. You can then run your app to see if it crashes or not.

Comment: I'll try and keep you updated.